# how to monitor file alterations in directory in java

Tags: java, csv

How to read csv files in a folder. New files will be added periodically in that folder. First while starting the java application it need to read all the csv file in that folder and after that it should read only new added csv file. Java application should not be killed after reading, it should run continuously. Thanks in advance

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));  
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{  
String[] employee = line.split(',');
.... 
}
```

Comment: Used bufferedReader for single file parse

Comment: Perhaps the java [file watch service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [FileAlterationMonitor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitor.html)

Example:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/io-commons/monitor/filealterationmonitor/org-apache-commons-io-monitor-filealterationmonitor-example/

For csv reading, I recommend to use opencsv.
Add following dependency into your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code Example

```
    private List<String[]> readCsv(String fileName) throws Exception {
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(',').build();
        // if your csv file doesn't have header line, remove withSkipLines(1)
        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(
                new FileReader(fileName)).withCSVParser(csvParser).withSkipLines(1).build()) {
            List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
            return r;
        }
    }
```

BTW, title of the question could be *how to monitor file alterations in directory*